# Return a Generic Type without specifying type parameters

Tags: c#, generics

There is something that I don't understand about generic class types that I need explained to me.

Let's take the following silly method as an example:

```
    public List<> RandomList()  //Note that the Compiler yells at you for not giving a type parameter
    {
        var RandObj = new Random();
        var myint = RandObj.Next(1,3);

        switch(myint)
        {
            case 1: var StringList = new List<string>{ "Test" };
                return StringList;

            case 2: var IntList = new List<int>{ 1,2,3,4 };
                return IntList;
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway to make a function like this work? I'm wondering if there is a way to set it so that I'm saying. "This function returns a list. I'm not sure what type of list it will return, but it will definitely be a list.

Comment: List<object> but that's not desirable...

Comment: It is more the principle i'm curious about. I don't have a specific implementation in mind right now, but the question has been bothering me.

Comment: for one it will never go to case 2,second parameter of next method is not inclusive its exclusive meaning for your case you need to do RandObj.Next(1,3);...lol nice edit:)

Comment: Thanks.  I never actually use random, I just thew it in here to express my thoughts, but now I know! =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you must return a type that is common to all of the possible options that your return object could be, for the two Lists you could return the best possible option for this situation is `IList`

```
public IList RandomList()
{
    var RandObj = new Random();
    var myint = RandObj.Next(1,3);
    switch(myint)
    {
        case 1: var StringList = new List<string>{ "Test" };
            return StringList;

        case 2: var IntList = new List<int>{ 1,2,3,4 };
            return IntList;
    }
}
```

Some other possible choices are `object`, `IEnumerable`,  and `ICollection`

Comment: Perfect, this helps explain what I needed to know.  If in the future I ever create a generic type that I want to be able to do something like this with, I need to make sure that the Generic type implements a non-generic interface that I can use as a return value.

Answer (score 3):

In principle, in the C# Language, as [specified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645596%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), you can not do this.

See K.4.2 Open and closed types `(Extracted Relevant Paragraph)`

> At run-time, all of the code within a generic type declaration is
>   executed in the context of a closed constructed type that was created
>   by applying type arguments to the generic declaration. Each type
>   parameter within the generic type is bound to a particular run-time
>   type. The run-time processing of all statements and expressions always
>   occurs with closed types, and open types occur only during
>   compile-time processing.

The compiler needs to be able to convert all open types to closed types. Hence it complains.

If you want a consistent external view, then [Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx) are the way to go. Here [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) would work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  `List<>` is a generic type definition but is not a true type in that it can only be used for reflection purposes.  They should be called templates as in C++ :P

Answer (score 0):

In general I agree with SH- in that C# really isn't designed to do this.  You can fake this (imperfectly)

```
    public IList<T> RandomList<T>() {
        T targetType = default(T);
        var RandObj = new Random();
        switch(targetType.GetType().Name) {
            case "String": 
                var StringList = new List<string>{ "Test" };
                return (IList<T>) StringList;

            case "Int32": 
                var IntList = new List<int>{ 1,2,3,4 };
                return (IList<T>) IntList;

            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Doing the means you have to account for all the generic types you would use with the class at compile time.  You could also use a 'dynamic' type to do this.

Comment: I"m a little bit confused at what this code does.  at what point does T get declared? when the function is called?  What would a call look like?

Comment: You specialize it when you call the function for example:              var lst = RandomList<String>();
            Console.WriteLine(lst.Count);

Answer (score 0):

While not possible with a generic type that you do not control, it is possible to do something similar as long as you have control of the object hierarchy.

Consider the following definitions:

```
public class Number { };
public class Number<T>: Number {};

public static class NumberGenerator {

   public static Number Generate ( double value ) { return new Number<double>(); }
   public static Number Generate ( int value ) { return new Number<int>(); }

}
```

While silly, it does fulfill the requirements that you outlined. Although it is really just standard polymorphism.